# Missing gems & db:migrate Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler

I'm trying to work through [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQ8_VOGj5H8) by Andrew Perkins.  When I get to `rake db:migrate` I get this error and similar subsequent errors every time I install the missing gems.

> Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
>   Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I've run the `bundle install` but not sure I've installed properly or with all the right dependencies.  I'm pretty new to Rails so don't have a great idea as to where I'm going wrong so any examples of proper installation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

this ensures that the `rake` command run is the one specified in your project's Gemfile. You can read more about [`bundle exec` in the docs](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html).